# UWP: Screenreader (JAWS) does not work in a webview

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, jaws-screen-reader

I load a local webpage in my webview, simply like this:

```
string url = "ms-appdata:///local/Templates/template.html";
_webView.Navigate(new Uri(url));
```

The webview needs to be compatible with JAWS (a screen reader).

It seems like JAWS completely ignores the text webview, even though it's
focused

Does anyone know how to make the webview accessible?

Also, Narrator on a phone works fine, but on desktop the identifier of the object is spoken instead of the text itself

Comment: I found out that my html has to be accessible, so i did that and it works now. Does anyone know how to block the screenreader from reading the link of the page?

Comment: This is obvious the JAWS screen reader issue.  Has no relationship with uwp developing. I recommend you to ask the JAWS team for supporting.